# String or binary data would be truncated in table 'Record_Company.dbo.bands', column 'name'. Truncated value: 'I'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below this is what I'm writing. On the last step it is crashing. Thank you for help. I tried what I found for example:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
INSERT INTO bands (name)
VALUES ('Iron Maiden');
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
GO
```

But it did not work.

```
CREATE TABLE bands (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
    name NVARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) -
)
CREATE TABLE Albums ( 
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
    name NVARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    release_year INT, 
    band_id INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (band_id) REFERENCES bands(id),
INSERT INTO bands (name)
VALUES ('Iron Maiden');
```

> String or binary data would be truncated in table 'Record_Company.dbo.bands', column 'name'. Truncated value: 'I'.

Comment: You have tagged your question [tag:mysql] but I am guessing you are using Microsoft SQL Server (the "dbo" is the clue).

Comment: Yes - you are right. Sorry for that. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: I have fixed the tags. On Stack Overflow, it is customary to use [tag:sql-server] to refer to the Microsoft product, and [tag:sql] if your question is about the SQL language generally (not a specific implementation).

Comment: `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` Don't start down this path of trying to avoid fixing a problem by turning warnings off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-nvarchar/

> `NVARCHAR(n)`
>
> Code language: SQL (Structured Query Language) (sql)
> In this syntax, n defines the string length that ranges from 1 to 4,000. **If you don’t specify the string length, its default value is 1.**

(emphasis mine)

So your `NVARCHAR` is interpreted as `NVARCHAR(1)` which means it can hold a string of only 1 character. Your string "Iron Maiden" is truncated to the first character, "I".

Comment: THANK YOU. Now it is working. Also thanks for the link on tutorial. Have a nice day.